# Properly reading in a CSV file in pandas with double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file, where each line is enclosed with double quotes, where the first field is not enclosed in double quotes, but all other fields are, like this -

```
"Col1,""Col2"",""Col3"",""Col4"",""Col5"",""Col6"",""Col7"""

"1,""entry "",""entry "",""entry"",""entry"",""entry"",""entry"""
"2,""entry "",""entry "",""entry"",""entry"",""entry"",""entry"""
```

and so forth and I'm trying to read it into a pandas dataframe. The desired output would be something like -

```
   Col1   "Col2" "Col3" "Col4"  "Col5" "Col6" "Col7"
0  1      entry  entry  entry   entry  entry  entry
1  2      entry  entry  entry   entry  entry  entry
```

I ran the following command on terminal - file 'filename.csv', and the output is the following - ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators

I tried various ways of changing the read_csv parameters, such as

input_data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep = ',',encoding = 'iso-8859-1', engine = 'python')

The output of that is a data frame with 2 columns and 100+ rows, where the first column is empty, and the second column contains all the data I actually want, when in fact I want a dataframe with 7 columns and 100++ rows, something like -

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96AH4.png)

I cannot post the real data because of confidentiality purposes unfortunately.

Could someone help me out here? The fix intuitively feels like a simple one, but I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: post minimum 2 rows of you csv data, and desired output

Comment: *I cannot post the data because of confidentiality purposes unfortunately.* Sure, but you could cleanse the data to avoid confidentiality issues. Just make a mock csv with dummy data.

Comment: FYI: *this* is a single python string with escaped doublequotes: `"Col1,""Col2"",""Col3"",""Col4"",""Col5"",""Col6"",""Col7"""`. I suspect that's not actually your CSV's contents, but the result of a `print` statement?

Comment: Hi, I have just added the screenshot of the current ouptut! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1. Remove starting and ending "(double quotes) for each line and use 
input_data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv' , sep = ',' )

Solution 2. Use parameter quoting =3 
input_data = pd.read_csv('temp.csv' , encoding = 'iso-8859-1', engine = 'python' ,sep = ',' , quoting =3)

Solution 3. Remove extra "" from each value (each column values will be exactly what you wanted)

Comment: No explanation is given for solution 2 neither a link to the docs